# Example where a differentiable function with differential value smaller than 1, but is not lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis

This question is in compare to theorem 9.19 from baby Rudin. which states that suppose f maps a convex open set E $\subset$ R$^n$ into R$^m$, f is differentiable in R and there is a real number M such that $ ||f'(x)|| \le M $ for every x $\in$ E . Then $$|f(b)-f(a)| \le M|b-a| $$ for all a $\in$ E,  b $\in$ E

$$ $$

If the set is not a convex open set, then the theorem will be incorrect.
IE, I am trying to find an example where $U$ is a connected open subset $\subset R^2 $ and a function $f : U \to R $ that is differentiable everywhere and satisfy $||Df(p)|| \le 1 $ for all p $\in U$. However, there is no $M \in R$ such that $ |f(x)-f(y)| \le M ||x-y|| $ for all x, y $\in U$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $U = \mathbb R^2 \setminus\{ (x, 0): x\leq 1\}$ and $f = \theta$ (the angle function).

Comment: I dont understand how to prove that this is not lipschitz

Comment: @mayflower: Hint: Let $x<0, y>0$ and consider $(x, y)$ and $(x, -y)$ for $|y|$ small.